# OPENSSL Save x509 certificate of a website

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509

I can see the certificate with this command

```
openssl s_client -host {HOST} -port 443 -prexit -showcerts
```

How can I save the x509 cert of the website in a PEM - File?

Comment: `man x509` should give enough clues, especially the `-outform PEM` option.

Comment: i think that `-outform`is just for converting files into PEM or DER files, but how can I download the x509 file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -host {HOST} -port 443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'  > cert.pem
```

then to get all certs in chain ,  a quick way could be

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -host {HOST} -port 443 -showcerts | awk '/BEGIN CERT/ {p=1} ; p==1; /END CERT/ {p=0}' > allcerts.pem
```

Comment: i tried that, but then i only get 1 certificate. but there are 4 or 5 certificates